# Excel clean search and match

Tags: excel

I have a list of grocery items that I'm trying to categorize. I used a ton of IFS and search to find and categorize and the formula keeps growing larger and bloated. I'm seeking help in finding an efficient way to resolve this issue.

```
=IFS(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Bolognese","EGG","MILK","Cheese","butter","Creme Brie","Tasting Board","Yogurt"},C2))),"Diary",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Ribs","Sirloin","Bone","MEAT","BEEF","CHICKEN","Turkey","Bacon","Pork","sausage","ham"},C2))),"MEAT",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Cereal","Oatmeal","Salad","Soup","Grillin' Beans","Stock,Cinnamon Rolls","Croutons"},C2))),"Canned_&_Packaged",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Sparkling","Smoothie","Shake","Powder","spring","life water","desserts","Purified","Wine","juice","coffee","bottles","chips","drink","powerade","gatorade","tea","k-cup","Vitaminwater","Hershey","goldfish","dessert","cocktail","Jerky","tropicana","snack","cookie","frappuccino","ice cream","Pistachio","Pops","Crackers","Tart","Rolls","Candy","Cake","Bars","Muffin","Bread","Bun","cheetos","peanuts","muffins","Fritos","doritos","nuts","Distilled Water","Mineral Water","Armor Water"},C2))),"Snacks&Beverages",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Cherries","Strawberries","Blueberries","Clementines","Mandarins","Asparagus","Personal Watermelons","Broccoli","Blackberries","Seedless","Avocado","Apple","Vegetable","potato","whole","peaches","blueberries","Fruit","orange","carrot","grapes","Tomato","peppers","onion"},C2))),"Fruits & Vegetables",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Skillet","French Fries","Chili","Pizza","ball park franks","Entre","pie","kit","Wings"},C2))),"Frozen",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Ketchup","Guacamole","Baking Mix","Oil","Sauce","Mayonnaise","Flour","cocoa","salt","Hummus","Dip","Sour Cream","Broth"},C2))),"Condiments_&_Sauces",SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Fillet","Shrimp","Tuna","seafood","Lobster"},C2))),"Seafood")
```

Comment: Use a lookup table and XLOOKUP.

Comment: I was able to resolve it with match search and index like the following: INDEX(Keyword!B:B,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND(Keyword!A:A,C2)),0)) But the flaw is that it's matching substring instead of subword. For example there "tea" inside steak, it's match the tea instead of "steak" . Any suggestions?

Comment: I stick by my original suggestion.